# SVG animation with mousemove function inside setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to create something with SVG that responds to mouse movement combined with random movement.

you can check the code here
https://jsfiddle.net/hass/Lfv2yjyf/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = document;
    var mysvg = d.getElementById("mysvg");

    var mx,my,random,xmid,ymid,input;

    setInterval(function() {
        //svg size
        var svgw = $("svg").width();
        var svgh = $("svg").height();

        //center point of svg
        xmid = svgw/2;
        ymid = svgh/2;

        //random numbers
        random = {
            a: Math.floor(Math.random()*25),
            b: Math.floor(Math.random()*25),
            c: Math.floor(Math.random()*25)
        };

        //add event to svg
        mysvg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
            //aqcuire mouse position relative to svg
            mx = e.clientX;
            my = e.clientY;

            //add <path> to svg
            input = '<path d="M ' + xmid + ',' + ymid + ' l ' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ' ' + ((mx-xmid)/2) + ',' + random.a + ' ' + ((mx-xmid)-((mx-xmid)/2)) + ',' + ((my-ymid)-random.a) + ' ' + '" stroke="orange" stroke-width="7" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />';
        });

        //display datas
        $("#status1").html("X Position : " + mx + "<br>Y Position: " + my + "<br><br>Center Point X: " + xmid + "<br><br>Center Point Y: " + ymid + "<br><br>Width: " + svgw + "<br>Height: " + svgh + "<br><br>Random Value a: " + random.a + "<br>Random Value b: " + random.b + "<br>Random Value c: " + random.c);

        $("#mysvg").html(input);
    }, 10);
});
```

My problem here is the random movement of the line at midpoint only responds when I move the mouse, I know it doesn't work because the random value is only acquired with mouse movement.

what I'm trying to do is I want the random movement even without the mouse movement.

so I want to know how I acquire the values of global object in setInterval every 10 milliseconds or whatever value I set at "setInterval" function but I prefer almost every millisecond so I could get the random vibrating effect.

I also tried to write the "path" outside of mousemove function and it works and this is something I wanted to achieve

https://jsfiddle.net/hass/d2L4hda5/

but the problem here is when I check the console (browser's development tool → console tab) the values of the mouse x and mouse y is "NaN". but the rendering works.

I cannot figure out what I'm missing here.

so I want to get some advice if second link is what I want to achieve and get the right values of mouse x and mouse y or any other technique that works best.

Regards.

Comment: I don't understand what you really need, I would maybe calculate the direction of the mouse and move to that point applying some randomness. I also suggest you to use the [d3 library](http://d3js.org/) when working with svg, it can [help a lot with paths](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/)

Comment: Thanks Mr. David for reply, I figured out what the problem was, thank you also for suggesting a library, I'll try d3 library if it would make my job easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you problem is here.  Is your problem that you can't seem to see the values iof mx and my in your browser tools?  How are you trying to read them?  Note that they aren't global variables. They are local to the `ready()` function.  So, for instance, you won't be able to see the value if you simply type `mx` into the console.

Note also, that you don't need to keep adding the mousemove event handler every time your interval timer function gets called.  It can be totally independent.  See below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = document;
    var mysvg = d.getElementById("mysvg");

    var mx,my,random,xmid,ymid,input;

    //svg size
    var svgw = $("svg").width();
    var svgh = $("svg").height();

    //center point of svg
    xmid = svgw/2;
    ymid = svgh/2;

    //add event to svg
    mysvg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        //aqcuire mouse position relative to svg
        mx = e.clientX;
        my = e.clientY;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        //random numbers
        random = {
            a: Math.floor(Math.random()*25),
            b: Math.floor(Math.random()*25),
            c: Math.floor(Math.random()*25)
        };

        //add <path> to svg
        input = '<path d="M ' + xmid + ',' + ymid + ' l ' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ' ' + ((mx-xmid)/2) + ',' + random.a + ' ' + ((mx-xmid)-((mx-xmid)/2)) + ',' + ((my-ymid)-random.a) + ' ' + '" stroke="orange" stroke-width="7" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />';

        //display datas
        $("#status1").html("X Position : " + mx + "<br>Y Position: " + my + "<br><br>Center Point X: " + xmid + "<br><br>Center Point Y: " + ymid + "<br><br>Width: " + svgw + "<br>Height: " + svgh + "<br><br>Random Value a: " + random.a + "<br>Random Value b: " + random.b + "<br>Random Value c: " + random.c);

        $("#mysvg").html(input);
    }, 10);

});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p id="status1"></p>
    <svg id="mysvg" width="300" height="300"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mr. Paul, I figured out why the value of mx was "NaN". it was because mx won't have any values until "mousemove" event happens.

thank you also for rearranging my code, it's more cleaner now :)