# d3 flickering line on setInterval

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am just learning d3 and I want to know if its the right way to render svg line everysecond?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>d3 test</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    //Width and Height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 50;

    //Create SVG Element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    //Global array
    var linedata = [];

    //random multiplier
    var randNum = 50;

    setInterval(function() {
        var random = {
            a: Math.floor(Math.random()*randNum),
        };

        linedata = [ "M 0 0 L 200 " + (100+random.a) ];

        line = svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(linedata)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path");

        line.attr("d", function(d) {
                return d;
            })
            .attr("stroke","orange")
            .attr("stroke-width", 7)
            .attr("fill","none");
    }, 10);

    setInterval(function() {
        svg.selectAll("path")
        .remove();
    }, 10);
</script>
```

**Problem**
My problem is that line keeps flickering even the time I set at setInterval is very fast.

what I want is the line wont flicker and renders smoothly every millisecond or not noticeable that it rerenders

what I want to achieve is similar to this one, but its in Javascript and Jquery not with d3 library

[SVG animation with mousemove function inside setInterval function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985042/svg-animation-with-mousemove-function-inside-setinterval-function/32987743#32987743)

Regards.

Comment: @altocumulus It's not jumping around, it's being deleted and recreated every 10ms

Comment: @RobertLongson Ah, you are right, I missed that. I delightedly withdraw my remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one function adding something and the other removing it, it's going to flicker. Just move the existing line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>d3 test</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    //Width and Height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 50;

    //Create SVG Element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    var line = svg.append("path")
            .attr("stroke","orange")
            .attr("stroke-width", 7)
            .attr("fill","none");

    //Global array
    var linedata = [];

    //random multiplier
    var randNum = 50;

    setInterval(function() {
        var random = {
            a: Math.floor(Math.random()*randNum),
        };

        linedata = [ "M 0 0 L 200 " + (100+random.a) ];

        line.data(linedata);
      
        line.attr("d", function(d) {
                return d;
            })
    }, 10);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Robert! solved my problem! big thumbs up!

Comment: Just a little improvement: Since you are only interested in updating the path's data, you can get rid of the call to `enter()` after binding the changed `linedata`. You won't need D3's enter selection.

Comment: Thank you for the advises Mr's :)
another question, what if I wanted to add more data in the array?
I tried adding one more data in the array but only 1 line is rendered.

Comment: @ha_ryu Ask another question.

Comment: @RobertLongson Hi! I asked another question :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055018/how-do-i-add-another-line-dynamically