# how do I add another line dynamically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create dynamic line that randomly moves on the page, I also want to move the tip of the line with mouse movement so I tried adding another data in "linedata" variable but it only renders 1 line.

the code below only has 1 data in "linedata" array, I tried something like

```
 var random = {
        a: Math.floor(Math.random()*randNum),
        b: Math.floor(Math.random()*randNum),
    };

linedata = [ "M 0 0 L 200 " + (100+random.a),
         "M 100 100 L 200 " + (100+random.b) ];
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>d3 test</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
//Width and Height
var w = 500;
var h = 50;

//Create SVG Element
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

var line = svg.append("path")
        .attr("stroke","orange")
        .attr("stroke-width", 7)
        .attr("fill","none");

//Global array
var linedata = [];

//random multiplier
var randNum = 50;

setInterval(function() {
    var random = {
        a: Math.floor(Math.random()*randNum),
    };

    linedata = [ "M 0 0 L 200 " + (100+random.a) ];

    line.data(linedata);

    line.attr("d", function(d) {
            return d;
        })
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a line and move the line by changing the x1/y1/x2/y2 as per the mouse pointer. See the function *mousemove*

For generating random lines see function *generateLines*

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

function generateLines() {
    var line = svg.append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "orange")
        .attr("stroke-width", 7)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("x1", generateRandomPoints())
        .attr("y1", generateRandomPoints())
        .attr("x2", generateRandomPoints())
        .attr("y2", generateRandomPoints())
        .attr("fill", "none");
}


function mousemove() {
    var t = d3.mouse(this);

    svg.selectAll(".line").attr("x1", t[0]).attr("y1", t[1]);
}
//make random points
function generateRandomPoints() {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * 500);
}
//this will generate random lines after an interval of 3 secs
setInterval(function () {
    generateLines();
}, 3000);
```

full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/wxgdsux1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply, sorry my explanation wasn't good enough,
suppose I have something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/7oarv0uw/

it doesn't work but if you paste the code and view in localhost(XAMPP, WAMP,WAMP) you can view the rendering.

so what I wanted to achieve was I want to have like for example 5 lines at the center initially, then I can move the end of the line with mousemovement like follow the mouse and each line has 2-3 points that randomly moves.

like this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985042/svg-animation-with-mousemove-function-inside-setinterval-function